Comedy / musical / western (?) with wandering guys and a horse
I saw this movie about 15 years ago, but i think it's older than that. Made between 1985 and 1995 i'd guess. It was english spoken and the actors where all white as far as I remember. 
I don't think there was much of a story line. 
There were this 4 or 5 guys wandering around with a horse, maybe looking for someone? It had a little bit of a western vibe to it, I think it was mainly a comedy. One of the guys was short and a bit funny looking. I think he had short curly brown hair. 
I remember one scene where they spot a sheep and the short guy excitingly unzips his pants. 
In another scene they all started singing (as in a musical) but ended up arguing about the tonescale they were singing in. 

Ok, one of my friends had also seen it at the time and was able to find the title: Alferd Packer: the musical (1993)
The storyline

Alfred Packer was a mountain guide and sole survivor of a party of
  pioneers that got lost in the mountains in winter. Accused and
  convicted of murdering and eating his travelling companions, he was to
  be executed by hanging.The movie begins at his trial, where he pleads
  his innocence to an unsympathetic audience. Only reporter Polly Pry
  will listen to his story, which is then related to the viewers in the
  form of flashbacks. As Packer and his gold-prospecting clients make
  their way through the forests and mountains, they encounter bemused
  Japanese Indians, an unimpressed group of mountain men and the brutal
  Rocky Mountain winter, all of which inspire the travellers to break
  out into song and dance.

Quotes:

George Noon: Oh, stop!
James Humphrey: That's sick!
Frenchy Cabazon: I agree! Nutter was singing in the wrong key!
Preston Nutter: No I wasn't! It was Loutzenheiser! I was singing in E flat minor.
Frenchy Cabazon: The SONG'S in F sharp major!
Shannon Bell: I think they're the same thing. I mean, E flat is the relative major of F sharp.
Frenchy Cabazon: No it isn't! The relative minor is three half-tones DOWN from the major, not up!
George Noon: No, it's three down. Like A is the relative minor of C major.
  O.D. Loutzenheiser: But isn't A sharp in C major?
Shannon Bell: Wait, are you singing mixolydian scales or something?
Frenchy Cabazon: A sharp is tonic to C major! It's the sixth!
James Humphrey: No it isn't!
Israel Swan: Well, it would be like a raised 13th if anything.

